# Clear text button

Tags: java, button, awt

I have a code which will clear the textfield when the button is pressed. it wont work.
heres the code:

```
 buttonButton.addActionListener(this); 
  field1TextField.setForeground(Color.black); 
  cleartextButton.addActionListener(this); 
  cleartextButton.setForeground(Color.black); 

 }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
   if(e.getSource() == buttonButton) { 
      add(buttonLabel);
      validate(); 
      add(field1TextField); 
      validate(); 
      add(cleartextButton);
      validate();
    if(e.getSource() == cleartextButton) {
        String cleartext = "";
        field1TextField.setText(cleartext);
        validate();

    }
       }     
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a closing brace to the first `if` statement in `actionPerformed`.

```
if(e.getSource() == buttonButton) {
   ...

} <--- add this
```

Comment: +1.. I'm staring at this code for 5 minutes and I couldn't notice this :D

Comment: that DIDNT HELP. it adds a problem instead of fixing it

Comment: and this is only part of the code. all braces are there

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: that is the error. your soultion didnt help. the error is still there

Comment: Each component that you're checking for in the `ActionListener` need to be checked in its own separate `if` statement. Having a nested `if` statement will never work as the source object of the action can only be a single component